# How to remove default event name in Vuetify V-Calendar?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am developing an application using API Rest as back-end and Vue.js as front-end. I implemented the framework Vuetify and I'm using the component V-Calendar which works like a charm. However, there is one fault I'm not able to correct.

When defining my events recovered from my Rest API, I include a property called "name" which appears as the title of my events in the calendar.

```
await this.getSlots();
    const slots = this.$store.getters["slots/getSlotData"];
    let slotEtat = "";

    if (slots != null) {
      for (let i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
        let heureDebut = slots[i].dateDebut.substring(11, 16);
        heureDebut = heureDebut.replace(":", "h");
        let heureFin = slots[i].dateFin.substring(11, 16);
        heureFin = heureFin.replace(":", "h");

        if(slots[i].placesLibres > 0) slotEtat = slots[i].placesLibres + " place(s) libre(s)";
        else if(slots[i].placesLibres < 0) slotEtat = "Slot surchargé (" + (Math.abs(slots[i].placesLibres) + slots[i].capacite) + "/" + slots[i].capacite + ")";
        else slotEtat = "Slot complet (" + (Math.abs(slots[i].placesLibres) + slots[i].capacite) + "/" + slots[i].capacite + ")"
                    
        events.push({
          name: heureDebut + " à " + heureFin + " | " + slotEtat,
          start: new Date(slots[i].dateDebut),
          end: new Date(slots[i].dateFin),
          color: this.getColorSlot(slots[i].placesLibres),
          timed: true,
          id: slots[i].id,
          commentaire: "Commentaire : " + slots[i].commentaire,
          isSlot: true
        })
      }
    }
```

However, the V-Calendar component automatically adds the "start" property in front of the "name" value, which results in the following in the user interface :

[Result in User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy0qB.png)

How can I prevent that data from appearing, only leaving the value of the property "name" ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `event` slot to customise how the events are displayed:

```html
<v-calendar
  ref="calendar"
  color="primary"
  :events="events"
>
  <template #event="event">
     TEST {{ event.timeSummary() }}
  </template>
</v-calendar>
```

The "event" parameter from the slot is the event to show. Then inside the `template` you can provide the html to use to display those events :)

Comment: And in order to access the properties defined when feeding "events", for example "name", I can use "event.eventParsed.input.name". Thank you!